# NTFS and Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, ntfs, file-permissions

I have defined a share in samba config, I am looking to modify permissions on a subfolder within MyShare to allow a specific NTFS group named MyFolder_Security modification rights and all other (with exception to root) groups/users read permissions only.  Having issues going into folder and making modification to group on particular folder stay on particular file within special folder.

```
[MyShare]
comment = "blah blah blah"
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
path = /xxx/xxxxx/
create mask = 0640
directory mask = 0750
admin users = @"domain\Domain Admins", @"domain\group A", @"domain\group B"
valid users = @"domain\Domain Admins", @"domain\group A", @"domain\group B"
nt acl support = Yes
inherit acls = yes
inherit owner = yes
inherit permissions = yes
```

the linux perissions on MyShare are: `drwxr-xr-x 116 root   root`

I have modified the group on folder  within  from: `drwxrwx---+    3 root Domain Users` to: `drwxrwx---+    3 root MyFolder_security`

NTFS properties have MyFolder_Secruity as Full Control Access, as well as root
I have a user that is allowed access to MyShare, and is not a member of MyFolder, and the user is capable of opening an xls spreadsheet within MyFolder and modifying a document.  Once this occurs the document permissions change from: `-rwxrwxr--+  1 root MyFolder_security` to: `-rwxrwxr--+  1 root Domain Users`

Unable to determine where the error is occuring.

Comment: please reformat the question using the 'code' feature so it's readable :)

Comment: not sure how to post using 'code' feature, can you provide instruction?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check

```
getfacl /path/to/MyShare
```

to get all of the acl's set on that directory?
The primary group of the user that opens the document is most likely "Domain Users", causing the permissions to change when they access the file.